# Using react + firebase, how do i create a dynamic route based on a collection item id?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

I'm having difficulties trying to make a dynamic route based on the ID of collection items using react and firebase. I can extract the ID but i'm unable to render a page in react since i don't know how.

I'm trying to do a map in my collection but i don't know how to consume id for each item.

```
   {protocol.map((item) => {
              return (
                <div key={item.id} className="flex justify-start underline underline-offset-3">
                  <Link to={`/protocol/${item.id}}`}>
                      {console.log(item.id)}
                    <div className="mt-2 hover:text-pink-600 duration-300">{item.name}</div>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              );
            })}
```

Comment: There are no routes in the code snippet you've shared, so it's unclear what any issue or problem is since we can't address issues in code we can't see. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] for what you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { collection, getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/config";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import "../assets/card.css";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Protocol = () => {
  const [protocol, setProtocol] = useState();
  let { id } = useParams();

  const docRef = doc(db, "protocols", id);

  const getInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        setProtocol(docSnap.data());
      } else {
        console.log("Document does not exist");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getInfo();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      adada {id}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Protocol;
```